# Trying to scrape data generated by ajax request using scrapy, but the ajax request redirects to home page

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scraping so i am not sure why i am getting this problem. I am trying to scrape customer vendor chats from anyvan.com. A normal job page of the site looks like [this](http://www.anyvan.com/view-listing/1935650). Clicking on the pink view button in the bids session sends an ajax request which then loads the chats. This XHR request can been seen in Developers tool -> Network -> filter XHR request.

I am using the following simple spider to simulate that request using scrapy but it seems that I am getting redirected to anyvan.com

```
class AVSpider(Spider):
    name = "anyvanscraper"
    allowed_domains = ["anyvan.com"]
    # This start URL is the job URL
    start_urls = ["http://www.anyvan.com/view-listing/1935650"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # This receives the response from the start url. But we don't do anything with it.
        url = 'http://www.anyvan.com/ajax-bid-comment/bid/14916780'
        return Request('http://www.anyvan.com/ajax-bid-comment/bid/14916780' , callback=self.parse_stores)
    
    def parse_stores(self, response):
        y = response.body
        f = open('html.txt','w')
        f.write(BeautifulSoup(y).prettify().encode('utf-8'))
```

Thanks in advance
Ellen

Comment: What is the idea of your work? getting the chat's text? (e.g. Xela79 said: Hi , what are your preferred collection & delivery dates? Regards, Alex)

Comment: @NimaSoroush - Yes, getting the chat's text is my requirement and the example you gave is the exact output that I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this header. You can add it to the request.

`"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"`

Something like this should work:

```
return Request('http://www.anyvan.com/ajax-bid-comment/bid/14916780' , callback=self.parse_stores, headers={"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"})
```